# Reducing PHP memory usage while reading from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I have to read all rows from a mysql table, then store all rows in a PHP array.

Example:

```
$res = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 1 ORDER BY type ASC, added DESC" );
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) { 
  $array[$row['cat']][$row['type']][] = $row; 
}
```

The table has 14300 rows and a size of 10.8MB

But when I check memory usage I get about 74MB, why?

Example:

```
echo memory_get_usage(); // return 74.6MB
echo memory_get_peak_usage(); // return 74.6MB
```

Is there a way to speed up / optimize the creation of the above array?

*PS: in the mysql table: type, cat and added are indexes*

Comment: Is there a way you can code so that you process the data in chunks as it's not just about the size of data but the time taken to process it.

Comment: Do you need all 14300 rows in your script? Are you already struggling with allocating 74 MB of memory (which is not that much), or do you fear that this gets even larger with more rows?

Answer (score 4):

> when I check memory usage I get about 74MB, why?

1. PHP, like most programs with a variable memory footprint, will start with a small allocation and as it approaches the available capacity it will ask the OS for more memory. There is a execution cost overhead for this and PHP doesn't know what the peak memory usage will be so it asks for a chunk. So when its running happily it will always have more memory than it uses.
2. In MyQSL, each record has the same structure. So it only needs to store the attribute names once. But PHP represents this as an array or arrays. Each  record element must also have a representation of the record structure.
3. Each data item in PHP is stored in a structure called a [ZVAL](https://www.zend.com/resources/php-extensions/basic-php-structures#:%7E:text=PHP%20is%20a%20dynamically%2Dtyped,%2C%E2%80%9D%20and%20two%20reserved%20fields.). This bundles a lot of meta-data. Of particular significance are the data type & the reference count (so PHP knows when the value can be discarded)
4. If PHP simply filled up its memory with names, zvals and data the footprint would be a lot smaller. But every time it wanted to retrieve a value it would need to apply a linear search through the data. That would take an EXORBITANT amount of time. It uses indexes and hashing to speed up de-referencing of variables.
5. In addition to the data (actually *before* considering the data) PHP needs to store the PHP source code in memory, and convert the human readable stuff into something closer to what the hardware understands. The last time I checked, this averaged around 3 times the size of the original code.

> Is there a way to speed up

The memory usage isn't going to affect performance much unless your machine is already in swap. However there is very likely scope for signficant reduction in the memory footprint based on what you've NOT told us: presumably there is some reason for reading all this data - i.e. you want to perform some sort of transformation on the data or send it somewhere other than PHPs memory. But we don't know what that is so can't advise.

Answer (score 2):

If you can process the data only once, do the processing in the loop.  That is, don't even have `$array`, simply process `$row` and then let `$row` be overwritten.

That might save only half of the 74MB.  The dirty little secret is that `mysqli_query` already brings all 14300 rows into RAM.  Your code then makes another copy of it all in `$array`.  There is a way to get the data a few rows at a time, but I deduced that the downsides of that technique was worst then the cost of the RAM.

Meanwhile, I do agree with @syncbean's answer (to paraphrase, "not-a-problem").  I learned long ago that fetching the entire `SELECT's` results my own array was not a big deal.  But, still, I do the above "consume row by row" technique because I am always thinking about "speed and space".  (I learned to program *before* machines ran at 1MHz and had 1MB of RAM.)

Comment: Rick, Excellent advice. Thank You.